# How to inherit unmanaged dependencies in submodules in sbt?

Tags: sbt

I have a project which looks like this, using sbt 0.13.2:

```
base
 - project
   - Build.scala
   - plugins.sbt
 - lib
   - unmanaged jar #1
   - unmanaged jar #2
 - core
    - src
      - .......
 - clp
    - src 
      - .......
 - server
    - src
      - ......
```

where `core` contains common code and `clp` and `server` are two related projects which both depend on `core`.

I'm trying to find the right mojo in `Build.scala` such that all three of these modules depend on `base/lib`. Currently I'm cheating by using a symlink'd `lib` dir in each of the modules, but I'd like to do it automatically without the symlinks.

Here's an example of `Build.scala` file - how should I modify this to make the dependencies work?

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object RootBuild extends Build {
  lazy val buildSettings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
    scalaVersion := "2.11.1",
    unmanagedBase := baseDirectory.value / "lib"
  )

  lazy val standardSettings = buildSettings ++ Seq(
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "2.1.6" % "test",
      "org.testng" % "testng" % "6.8.8"
    )
  )

  lazy val Projects = Seq(root, core, clp)

  lazy val root = Project("root", file("."), settings=standardSettings) aggregate(core, clp)
  lazy val core = Project("core", file("core"), settings=standardSettings)
  lazy val clp = Project("clp", file("clp"), settings=standardSettings) dependsOn core
  lazy val server = Project("server", file("server"), settings=standardSettings) depensOn core
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a correct `build.sbt`:

```
lazy val a, b = project settings(
  Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
    unmanagedBase := (unmanagedBase in ThisProject).value
  ): _*
)
```

The idea is to set `unmanagedBase` for the submodules based upon the value of the setting in the root project (that's defined implicitly).

In your particular case it'd be as follows:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object RootBuild extends Build {
  lazy val buildSettings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
    scalaVersion := "2.11.1"
  )

  lazy val standardSettings = buildSettings ++ Seq(
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "2.1.6" % "test",
      "org.testng" % "testng" % "6.8.8"
    )
  )

  lazy val submoduleSettings = standardSettings ++ Seq(
    unmanagedBase := (unmanagedBase in ThisProject).value    
  )

  lazy val root = project in file(".") settings(standardSettings: _*) aggregate(core, clp)
  lazy val core = project settings(submoduleSettings: _*)
  lazy val clp = project settings(submoduleSettings: _*) dependsOn core
  lazy val server = project settings(submoduleSettings: _*) dependsOn core
}
```

Comment: It should be `unmanagedBase := (unmanagedBase in LocalRootProject).value`

Comment: @James What's the version of sbt you use? I haven't checked it out with the recent versions.

Comment: My sbt version is 0.13.

Comment: @James Uh oh. You should certainly upgrade at your earliest convenience (it's sbt 1.3.4 time).