# How to add external jar files to a spark scala project

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, jar, sbt

I am trying to use an LSH implementation of Scala(https://github.com/marufaytekin/lsh-spark) in my  Spark project.I cloned the repository with some changes to the sbt file (added Organisation) [image: sbt file of LSH Implementation]

To use this implementation , I compiled it using sbt compile and moved the jar file to the "lib" folder of my project and updated the sbt configuration file of my project , which looks like this ,
[image: sbt file of my main project]

Now when I try to compile my project using sbt compile , It fails to load the external jar file ,showing the error message "unresolved dependency: com.lendap.spark.lsh.LSH#lsh-scala_2.10;0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: not found".
Am i following the right steps for adding an external jar file ? 
How do i solve the dependency issue

Comment: Please avoid posting screenshots and use the `code` formatting to put your sbt configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, you can build the lsh-spark project and add the jar in your spark application.
To add the external jars, addJar option can be used while executing spark application. Refer [Running spark application on yarn](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html)

Answer (score 1):

This issue isn't related to spark but to `sbt` configuration.

Make sure you followed the correct folder structure imposed by sbt and added your jar in the `lib` folder, as explained [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Library-Dependencies.html) - `lib` folder should be at the same level as `build.sbt` (cf. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28638368/where-does-the-lib-directory-for-unmanaged-jars-in-sbt-directory-structure-go)).

You might also want to check out this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129227/how-to-include-an-external-jar-file-into-the-jar-with-package).

Comment: I checked folder structure is fine .